# Continuity of positive and negative parts of a function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function where $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with standard Euclidean topology.  I need to show that $f^+:=\max\{f,0\}$ and $f^-:=-\min\{f,0\}$ are continuous. Am really stuck on this, so any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: $f^{+}$ is continuous because it can be rewritten as a function composition $f^{+} = g \circ f$ where $g : \mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto \max(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 4):

max{f,0}= (|f|+f)/2. Since $f$ is cont. so is $|f|$ and hence $f^+$ is cont.

Can you find similar expression for $f^-$?

Comment: $f^-=(|f|-f)/2$ but how do I show that $|f|$ is continuous, if $X$ is a metric space then it is easy using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, but if $X$ is just a general top space, how would go about showing $|f|$ is continuous?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jens: |f|= g composed f where g:$\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $g(x)=|x|$. g and f are cont. and hence so is their composition.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a function $g:X\to\Bbb R$ is continuous if for every $x\in X$ and every $\epsilon>0$, there is a neighborhood $U\ni x$ such that $\forall y\in U:|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. I'm just writing this explicitly so that you can see how this comes together.

The theorem follows easily from $|f^+(x)-f^+(y)|\le|f(x)-f(y)|$, since the "positive/negative part" maps are [metric maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_map) (you can also show this explicitly). Insert into the definition and you're done.